# how can i update ManyToManyField child attribute in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have two forms. i want to update the book title and lesson name which is belong from a book too. i am getting this error `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute '_meta'` when i click on update url of a book. would you like to tell me how can i solve this issue?
here is the trackback of error.

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/NLS/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/project/NLS/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/project/NLS/src/report/views.py", line 54, in book_update_form
  lession_form = LessonForm(instance=book.lesson)
  File "/home/project/NLS/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 294, in __init__
  object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "/home/project/NLS/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 85, in model_to_dict
  opts = instance._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at / report/genrate/1/
Exception Value: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

models.py

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lesson = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'lesson']


class LessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ['name']
```

views.py

```
def book_update_form(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    b_form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=book)
    l_form = [LessonForm(request.POST, prefix=str(
        lesson.pk), instance=lesson) for lesson in book.lesson.all()]

    if b_form.is_valid() and all([lf.is_valid() for lf in v_form]):
        book_update = b_form.save(commit=False)
        book_update.save()
        for lf in l_form:
            lesson_form = lf.save(commit=False)
            lesson_form.book = book_update
            lesson_form.save()
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        book_update = BookForm(instance=book)
        lession_form = LessonForm(instance=book.lesson)
    context = {
        'book_update': book_update,
        'lesson_form': lesson_form
    }
    return render(request, 'update.html', context)
```

Comment: you have error in `for lesson in book.lesson.all()`. lesson is a ForeignKey, so it contains only one element. If you want to have many lessons in one book, so use `ManyToManyField`

Comment: dear i also use `ManyToManyField` then i am getting `_meta` error. can i update my question with `ManyToManyField` ?

Comment: update it and show error messages

Comment: now its updated please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have error in `[lf.is_valid() for lf in v_form]`. `v_form` is not defined, probably you want to use l_form
2. `lesson_form.book = book_update`. `Lesson` model doesn't have book attribute, so you don't need this line
3. in your `else` case you create `lession_form = LessonForm(instance=book.lesson)`. book.lesson is `ManyToManyField`, so you have error here too.
   i would refactor your code this way:

> ```
> def book_update_form(request, pk):
>     book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
>     b_form = BookForm(request.POST or None, instance=book)
>     l_form = [LessonForm(request.POST or None, prefix=str(
>         lesson.pk), instance=lesson) for lesson in book.lesson.all()]
>
>     if request.POST and b_form.is_valid() and all([lf.is_valid() for lf in l_form]):
>         b_form.save()
>         for lf in l_form:
>             lesson_form = lf.save()
>         return redirect('dashboard')
>     context = {
>         'book_update': b_form,
>         'lesson_form': l_form# it's better to rename this variable to lesson_form_list
>     }
>     return render(request, 'update.html', context)
> ```

Comment: dear please can you explain how can you `lesson_form` in html template? i am using like  this `{{ lesson_form }}` and i am getting this `[]` in html...